# Hunspell Part-Of-Speech tagger?

Tags: c++, pos-tagger, hunspell, part-of-speech

Is there a way to use Hunspell as a Part-Of-Speech tagger?

It's for use with C++, if Hunspell can't we'll use LanguageTool, but it involve a JVM.

Comment: Isn't hunspell a text-based spell checker? Speech needs to go through Voice Recognition to become text. And the problem with that isn't that it produces misspelled words, but meaningless output when it messes up homophones.

Comment: POS tagging doesn't refer to audio speech, it's a tool for recognizing the "type" of a word. For example: "cars" part-of-speech tag is "noun, plural". It's text-based too.